# Scrollable TabLayout where current Tab is always in center

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I would like to design a `TabLayout` for an android app where the selected tab "button" is always in the center. Unfortunately I can only get the selected tab to be nearly in the center. Here are some pictures how it should look like:
[image: Right Tab] [image: Mid Tab]

Does anybody know how I am able to achieve this?